# Не работает extends 'base.html' на хостинге

Tags: python, html, flask, хостинг

Решил загрузить сайт на хостинг. Добавил в виртуальное окружение python, flask.
Однако страница index.html отображается некорректно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом верху видна строчка extends 'base.html', и я подозреваю, что вся проблема кроется в ней(в этом файле лежат все link и meta). Я уже двое суток пытаюсь найти решение этой проблемы,но, к сожалению, не смог. Файл base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ,user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">
    <link href="../static/static.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.1/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark  bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li class="nav-item" style="">
                        <a class="nav-link " aria-current="page" href="/"><h4>Главная</h4></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0" style="grid-auto-flow: initial">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown" style="padding-right: 10%">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink"
                                   role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <h4>Обо мне</h4>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark"
                                    aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/education"><h5>Образование и опыт работы</h5>
                                    </a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/publications"><h5>Мои публикации</h5></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/videos"><h5>Видео и онлайн курсы</h5></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/prices"><h5>Программы и консультации</h5></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link " href="/contacts"><h5>Контакты</h5></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</main>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <style>
        .conteiner div {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 186px
        }

    </style>
    <div class="container marketing">
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Карпинская Валерия Юльевна.<br><span class="text-muted"> Психолог, доктор психологических наук, доцент. </span>
                </h2>
                <br>
                <h5 class="featurette-heading"><span class="text-muted">Сознание, восприятие и действие, иллюзии восприятия, когнитивная наука, познание, сенсомоторная интеграция</span>
                </h5>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h4 class="featurette-heading"><span class="text-muted">Психология без мистики и шаманства</span></h4>
                <br>
                <h3 class="featurette-heading"><span class="text-muted">Автор научных статей и книг, автор и соавтор он-лайн образовательных и практических
                    курсов по психологии, эксперт лаборатории нейоровизуализации института мозга им Н.П. Бехтеревой,
                    руководитель научно-исследовательской работы в научно-методическом центре сенсомоторной интеграции
                    ООО "Сова-нянька" психолог-консультант.</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
                <img src="../static/photo_2021-12-29_09-21-49.jpg" width="250px" height="400px" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row-featurette">
            <div class="conteiner">
                <img src="../static/photo_2022-02-02_22-47-08.jpg" width="33%" height="5%" alt=""/>
                <img src="../static/photo_2022-02-02_22-47-13.jpg" width="33%" height="5%" alt=""/>
                <img src="../static/photo_2022-02-02_22-47-30.jpg" width="33%" height="5%" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

        <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: не знаю играет ли роль, но в глаза бросилось сразу `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Нет,я пробовал убирать. Это роли не играет